# Escaped HTML in mod tools' duplicate auto-flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, design, moderator-tools

In the german.SE moderator tools, a post has a weird duplicate flag. This HTML is probably not supposed to be escaped.

[image: image description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will go out in the next build.